# calculate loop fields with MySql php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have an HTML table which is getting data from MySql.

existingbankproducts table is below:

[image]

I have 2 calculated fields which need to sum up the numbers that I get. The fields that are needed to calculate is Balance and MonthlyCommitment.

The code I use to get the result from MySql is below:

```
<?php
$stmt2 = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM applicantpersonaldetails apd "
. "INNER JOIN existingbankproducts ext ON apd.ApplicantID = ext.ApplicantID "
. "WHERE apd.AccountID =:accountId AND apd.applicantType ='main';");

$stmt2->bindParam(':accountId', $accountId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
//if account id data type is varchar change the last parameter to `PDO::PARAM_str`
$stmt2->execute();

if ($stmt2->rowCount() > 0) {
?>


<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Financial Institution</th>
        <th>Product Type</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
        <th>Monthly Commitment</th>
    </tr>
<?php
while ($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type = "text" name = "finanIns1" id = "finanIns1" value="<?php echo $row['FinanicalInstituion']; ?>" readonly></td>

        <td>
            <input list = "proTypeList" name = "proType1" id = "proType1" value="<?php echo $row['ProductType']; ?>"readonly >

        </td>
        <td id = "balance"><input type = "number" name = "balance1" id = "balance1" value="<?php echo $row['Balance']; ?>"readonly></td>
        <td id = "MonthyComm"><input type = "number" name = "monthlyComm1" id = "monthlyComm1" value="<?php echo $row['MonthlyCommitment']; ?>"readonly></td>

    </tr>

<?php
}
} else {
?>
    <div class="">
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; No Data Found ...
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>                                                
    <?php
    while ($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $totalBalance = 0;

    $totalBalance += $row['Balance'];

    $totalMonthlyComm = 0;

    $totalMonthlyComm +=$row['MonthlyCommitment'];
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>Total:</td>
        <td><input readonly></td>
        <td id="balance"><input type="number" name="totalBalance" id="totalBalance" value="<?php echo $totalBalance; ?>" min="0" readonly></td>
        <td id="MonthyComm"><input type="number" name="totalMonthlyComm" id="totalMonthlyComm" value="<?php echo $totalMonthlyComm; ?>" min="0" readonly></td>

    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

I am able to retrieve the data from MySql. However, it is not able to sum up the totalBalance and totalMonthlyComm at the end of my table.

Comment: You must shift $totalBalance = 0; and $totalMonthlyComm = 0; before loop start.

Comment: Can you please show me the array of result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to loop through the database result only once:

```
<?php
$stmt2 = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM applicantpersonaldetails apd "
. "INNER JOIN existingbankproducts ext ON apd.ApplicantID = ext.ApplicantID "
. "WHERE apd.AccountID =:accountId AND apd.applicantType ='main';");

$stmt2->bindParam(':accountId', $accountId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
//if account id data type is varchar change the last parameter to `PDO::PARAM_str`
$stmt2->execute();
$totalBalance = 0;
$totalMonthlyComm = 0;
if ($stmt2->rowCount() > 0) {
?>


<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Financial Institution</th>
        <th>Product Type</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
        <th>Monthly Commitment</th>
    </tr>
<?php
while ($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $totalBalance += $row['Balance'];
    $totalMonthlyComm +=$row['MonthlyCommitment'];

?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="finanIns1" id = "finanIns1" value="<?php echo $row['FinanicalInstituion']; ?>" readonly></td>
        <td><input list="proTypeList" name="proType1" id="proType1" value="<?php echo $row['ProductType']; ?>" readonly></td>
        <td id="balance"><input type="number" name="balance1" id="balance1" value="<?php echo $row['Balance']; ?>" readonly></td>
        <td id="MonthyComm"><input type="number" name="monthlyComm1" id="monthlyComm1" value="<?php echo $row['MonthlyCommitment']; ?>" readonly></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?><tr>
        <td>Total:</td>
        <td><input readonly></td>
        <td id="balance"><input type="number" name="totalBalance" id="totalBalance" value="<?php echo $totalBalance; ?>" min="0" readonly></td>
        <td id="MonthyComm"><input type="number" name="totalMonthlyComm" id="totalMonthlyComm" value="<?php echo $totalMonthlyComm; ?>" min="0" readonly></td>

    </tr>
</table>
<?php
} else {
?>
    <div class="">
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; No Data Found ...
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your lines from while as :

```
<?php
  $totalBalance = 0;
  $totalMonthlyComm = 0;    
  while ($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $totalBalance += $row['Balance'];
   $totalMonthlyComm +=$row['MonthlyCommitment'];
  }
?>
<tr>
    <td>Total:</td>
    <td><input readonly></td>
    <td id="balance"><input type="number" name="totalBalance" id="totalBalance" value="<?php echo $totalBalance; ?>" min="0" readonly></td>
    <td id="MonthyComm"><input type="number" name="totalMonthlyComm" id="totalMonthlyComm" value="<?php echo $totalMonthlyComm; ?>" min="0" readonly></td>

</tr>
```

Comment: Your solution would not work, as `$stmt2->fetch()` would return FALSE. (Because all the rows of the result set have been consumed by the first `while` loop).